# Como funciona a integração Spring JSF, e qual a participação do Filtro InternalResourceViewResolver e como deve ser configurado para sua integração?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spring-mvc, jboss

Estou estudando para iniciar um projeto de um sistema Web distribuído, que terá interfaces simples em alguns contextos, porém outros demandará uma estrutra da interface que fará necessário a adoção de um Framework como PrimeFaces para contribuir na construção da interface.

Como o sistema usa Spring também vi que devo usar o Spring, o que já fui informado e está sendo um grande desafio integrar com o JSF além dos containers.

Vi que o Filtro `InternalResourceViewResolver` é parte fundamental neste processo, estou certo? como é sua participação? e Como deve ser parametrizado?

## Obs:

> O Sistema é baseado em Spring e deve funcionar nos principais containers de aplicação, será um sistema aberto (código disponível no GitHub) porém de uso restrito, a licença ainda está sendo discutida.

Comment: @Delpino qual versão do Spring você está usando?

Comment: Outra pergunta é quais as razões de vc precisar de um Container EE?

Comment: Você diz em relação ao Spring? quando me fazem esta pergunto, faço outro por que não?

Comment: Bom, bom essa pode ser uma discussão complexa, acho que não é o objetivo aqui. É que se você não usar muitos recursos do container, pode ser mais fácil apenas utilizar Spring e um servidor Web, até mesmo o Jetty, que é embedado, mas como eu disse, não é o foco, o que vc precisa é saber como funciona a Integração entre JSF e Spring,  me passe a versão do Spring que vc está utilizando, pois se for abaixo da 3.X eu não posso responder com segurança.

Comment: @FilipeGonzagaMiranda, a minha escolha por um container, é porque em última instancia de desenvolvimento da aplicação estarei usando EJBs e DataSources plugáveis entre outros recursos que não sei ainda se o Spring poderá me atender. o JBoss sempre foi minha primeira escolha, sendo o Spring minha segunda para facilitar a migração para outros containers entregando a ele tarefas que possam divergir entre os containers.

Comment: A versão do Spring é 4.1